# Query the PCMCIA slot, prevent or delay windows shutdown

Tags: windows, smartcard

I noticed that people occasionally forget their smartcards in the pcmcia slots of their windows laptops. Is there a way to query the pcmcia slot and check if a smartcard is inside it? And is it possible to query this when a laptop gets locked or when windows is shutdown and notify the user about the smartcard still being inside the device?

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any ready to use existing solution but (assuming that we are on the website dedicated to developers) it should be fairly simple to write windows service application that would be using [Winscard Smart Card API](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/aa374731.aspx#smart_card_functions) to do exactly what you need.

Comment: Thank you very much. That pointed me into the right direction. I guess it will work.